# Wifi Noise Level with AR9271 chipset

Tags: wifi-configuration, ubuntu-18.04, noise

Hi I'm trying to get the noise level on my Wifi adapter (AR9271 atheros chipset) ? Using Ubuntu 18.04

/cat/proc/wireless gives me -256dBm which means the driver isn't reporting the noise

I have installed wavemon but there is no noise level reported when I hit F2.

Is there a way to get the noise level of a Wifi Adapter?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the correct operating system tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.